# Python/ElasticSearch: delete alias without knowing index name

Tags: python, elasticsearch

In my ElasticSearch server, I have alias "my-alias-1" pointing to an unknown index.

How can I removed the alias using Python? The doc I search always show I need to know the index name as well.

Comment: can't you just query the index behing the alias ?

Comment: If you know alias name, how is that hard to delete the alias ? Or do you want to delete index too ?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the `elasticsearch-py` client, the low level one - https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete_alias

if you're using another library or client, then you need to do the equivalent of sending a HTTP `DELETE my-alias-1` request to Elasticsearch